# .htaccess pretty URL resulting in 404

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite `mypage.com/foo.php` as `mypage.com/foo`. My rewrite changes the URL correctly, however the resultant page is a 404.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
# Setup conditions for internal rewrite of Foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite for TDS
RewriteRule ^foo/$ /foo.php [L,QSA]

# External redirect for Foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+foo\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /foo/? [R=301,L]
```

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Most probably you want to redirect this `mypage.com/foo`, which is the entered UR, the one displayed by the browser, to: `mypage.com/foo.php`, which is the resource that silently handles the request. I don't think you want your visitors to enter `mypage.com/foo.php` to go to `mypage.com/foo`. If that is correct, the last rule-set is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Setup conditions for internal rewrite of Foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Rewrite for TDS
RewriteRule ^foo mypage.com/foo.php [L,QSA]
```

Try this..

Comment: 500 error can be fixed by your server side program not client side so check your server side parameters..

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Apache take a look at the error.log file, it should provide you with some useful information.

If you're on a Windows Server, I am sure there is a similar log file to look at.

Comment: No problem, always look at the error.log file when you have any server errors. Has saved me many times.